# Long time click operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to write a python script for automation of smoke test of a web application. I am entering login credentials username and password and clicking on Login button using python selenium libraries. But the login operation after clicking login button is taking long time. I want to cancel login operation after 30 seconds wait. Can some one help me in that operation. Sample code is the below one.

```
try:
  driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("username")
  driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("password")
  driver.find_element_by_id("LoginID").click()
  

except NoSuchElementException as exception:

 if "LoginID" in str(exception):
 print("Login button not clicked")
```

Comment: add a link to login page

Comment: @vitaliis, Can you please provide me code for that

Comment: I cannot suggest an answer until I see this login page or its html code

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I want to cancel login operation"? The web page is still loading. What do you want to do now?

Comment: @Prophet, driver.find_element_by_id("LoginID").click()  operation is taking long time. Here my requirement is to wait for 30 seconds, if the next page doesn't load in 30 minutes then cancel the login operation and then proceed with next line of code instead of waiting click operation to complete

Comment: But what can you continue doing if you didn't log in?
I'm trying to catch the logic

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking for an element that always exists after you login successfully

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_id("LoginID").click()
    

try:
    any_element = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.*any method*, '*whatever is here')))#This should look for an element that always exists after you login successfully(you are free to chose that element)
    print "Page is ready!"
except TimeoutException:# if the previous element wasn't found after 30 sec it will reload the page to cancel the login operation
    driver.refresh()
    print("Login button not clicked")
```